# HP Deskjet 1050 worked with Ubuntu 13.04 but not printing with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, hp

I have a HP Deskjet 1050(All-in-one) which previously worked fine on Ubuntu 13.04 but since upgrading to 14.04 I'm having problems.

I re-installed hplip, now on version  hplp-3.14.4. 
All seemed to go fine but I still can't print.

What
should I do now - has anyone else got the same problem?

Comment: Try purging instead of removing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to got to Home-Cups 1.7.2 and follow through the various steps.
Printer has printed a test page so assume all is well.

If I had known to go to [CUPS Help](https://www.cups.org/documentation.html) I would have saved myself a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Install all the applications that HP printers need to work :

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd printer-driver-hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip printer-driver-hpcups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui djtools
```

Comment: E: Package 'hpijs' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'hplip-cups' has no installation candidate  Ubuntu does not auto-detct the printer and I don't know what the URI should be, it is a USB device

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment 
 
Try purging instead of removing.  (above)

Comment: I edited the answer. Try now.

Comment: Edited version seems to work, but printer still not detected. What URI do I use?

Comment: Tried ray@ray-Aspire-5735:~$ mtp-detect 
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.

Comment: Still trying to get the printer 'found'. Have entered URI as ipp://cups-server/printers/printer.queue and alternately as ipp://printer/ray/ipp, neither seems to improve things. Tried changing the printer cable, no joy.

Comment: Sequence of events is - Laptop restarted with printer ON.   'Settings/Printers/Properties..... Printer Stutus - Connected to Local Host' then -
'Print Test Page....Processing Page 1........Unable to Locate Printer'

Seems, (TO ME !) that the printer is being recognised from the 'connected to local host' bit and the fact that it tries to printthe Test Page. Or am Is that just wishful thinking on my part?